# How can I use wildcards with MyVlookup function?

Tags: excel, vba

When calling the below function in Excel by using **=MyVlookup(B1,Sheet1!A:A,1)** I get what I want.

> Function MyVlookup(Lval As Range, c As Range, oset As Long) As Variant
>
> > Dim cl As Range
> >  
> >     For Each cl In c.Columns(1).Cells
> >  
> >     If UCase(Lval) = UCase(cl) Then
> >  
> >     MyVlookup = cl.Offset(, oset - 1)
> >  
> >     Exit Function
> >  
> >     End If
> >  
> >     Next
> >  
> >     End Function

But I'd like to use wildcards around **B1**, e.g. **"*"&B1&"*"**. When I do that I get an error (#ARG!).
I tried using double quotation marks, but it didn't work, either. What should I do to overcome this?

Comment: B1 is passed to a parameter which you've defined in your UDF as `Range`. If you want to pass a string instead then you need to update the parameter type to `As String`  If you need wildcard capability you'll also need to use `Like` instead of `=`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As this is not my code, and I'm not sure what should be changed to make it work, could you make a suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code

```
Function MyVlookup(Lval As Range, c As Range, oset As Long) As Variant

    Dim cl As Range
    For Each cl In c.Columns(1).Cells
        If InStr(1, UCase(cl), UCase(Lval), vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            MyVlookup = cl.Offset(, oset - 1)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

**String beginning with**

```
Function MyVlookup(Lval As Range, c As Range, oset As Long) As Variant

    Dim cl As Range
    For Each cl In c.Columns(1).Cells
        If cl Like Lval & "*" Then
            MyVlookup = cl.Offset(, oset - 1)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

**string ending with**

```
Function MyVlookup(Lval As Range, c As Range, oset As Long) As Variant

    Dim cl As Range
    For Each cl In c.Columns(1).Cells
        If cl Like "*" & Lval Then
            MyVlookup = cl.Offset(, oset - 1)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

**string which contains**

```
Function MyVlookup(Lval As Range, c As Range, oset As Long) As Variant

    Dim cl As Range
    For Each cl In c.Columns(1).Cells
        If cl Like "*" & Lval & "*" Then
            MyVlookup = cl.Offset(, oset - 1)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got the same error. However, Tim's solution above did the trick.

Comment: Now I did. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

```
Function MyVlookup(Lval As String, c As Range, oset As Long) As Variant

Dim cl As Range

    Lval = UCase(Lval)

    For Each cl In c.Columns(1).Cells
        If UCase(cl) Like Lval Then
            MyVlookup = cl.Offset(, oset - 1)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: Wow is all I can say! Thanks!